# Continue running JS if user navigates away

Tags: javascript, html

So I have some sort of "long" operation that must be ran in client's browser. I want to let it run even if the user navigates away from that particular page (though stays in the same domain). Is it even possible with JS and, if so, what is the basic approach??

Comment: Nope, if the user closes the browser, your JavaScript stops running.  Long operations on the client is a bad model. At the very least, you have to have a way to recover from the browser being closed by keeping track of your progress.

Comment: You might be able to use an iframe to run some event depending on how your site is structured, you would have to put the main site in it's own iframe though, or have a popup.

Comment: If you create a javascript app with its own internal routing, you can accomplish this by creating 'page' components that all listen to your operation store.  This won't help if the user leaves the app completely, refreshes their browser, or closes their browser without a session stored server-side tracking progress.  But, at that point, it's probably better to have the whole operation occur server-side.